# Render a partial view via ajax in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, render, single-page-application, rails-routing

currently i am trying to make my rails app single paged, but i am having some problems with the rendering of partials.. Now here is my controller code:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @welcome = WelcomeController.new
        render :partial => 'enjoy'
    end

    def index
        if params[:id] == 'enjoy'
            @partial_view = 'enjoy'
        elsif params[:id] == 'about'
            @partial_view = 'about'
        else
            @partial_view = 'main'
        end
    end

end
```

So this controller is linked to my view, and for the pages to change i was using the code in the index action, but now i am trying to use the thing in the create action. The code of my index.html.slim where i am trying to call the create action is:

```
        div id="content"

        = form_tag(:url => {:action => 'create'},
                :update => "content", :position => :bottom,
                :html => {:id => 'subject_form'}, 
                :remote => true)

            = submit_tag 'Add'
```

So on button click 'Add', i am expecting the content from _enjoy.slim.html, which is my partial to go into the div with id "content", but when the button is clicked and the _enjoy.html.slim is rendered it loads on top of the whole index.html.slim page... So i am stuck at that, how can i make it load into the certain div?

Thanks a ton to anyone who has an answer to this one {:

Comment: Which version of rails are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @welcome = WelcomeController.new
    # Remove the render
  end

  def index
    # No change
  end    
end
```

View:

```
div id="content"

= form_tag({:action => 'create'}, :id => 'subject_form',  :remote => true) do
  = submit_tag 'Add'
```

Create welcome/create.js.erb and add the following line to it:

`$('#content').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'welcome/enjoy') %>")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! <3 I was just wondering, is it possible to make it run with create.js.slim file? Cause i tested it and it did not happen ;[

Comment: Maybe? Try to rename the file to create.js.slim. You'll have to change the content to: `$('#content').html("#{ j render(:partial => 'welcome/enjoy') }")`

Comment: Umm.. Why #{ j renderer... and not ={ j renderer.. ?

Comment: Because `#{}` is used for text interpolation in slim.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a `create.js.erb` file in your 'welcome' views directory and there you have to render the partial per ajax:

```
$("#content").html("<%= j render(:partial => 'welcome/enjoy') %>");
```

and in the create action of the controller you have to respond to javascript:

```
def create
 ...
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js
 end
end
```